# System freezes when apt-get tries to unpack a particular package

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Each time I run an APT or `dpkg` command, it does what it supposed to do until it come to the package `masalla-icon-theme` (which I'm not using anymore). The package downloads, but as soon as apt tries to unpack it, my computer freezes. This is the error I get when trying to update packages:

```
dpkg: error processing package masalla-icon-theme (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should 
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

I tried waiting but it always stay stuck.

I tried removing the package from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` or by emptying the APT cache but this didn't help.

Comment: Open a Terminal and type `sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list` remove the line that contains 'masalla-icon-theme'  and do an apt-get update.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the package first, you can do this via terminal by typing : `sudo apt-get remove masalla-icon-theme` or by using synaptic,  then run this command :  `sudo apt-get install -f` ,
bytheway, this problem happened when you install external package in your system ,

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use `apt-get remove <...>`. It says that I need to run `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. But when I do, my computer crashes.